# How can we change our authentication for SE?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I originally signed into SE using a facebook account, and I would like to change that to a SE account.  I've looked but I can't seem to find a way.  Does anyone know of one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your user page:

https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/4595/johngb

- click "my logins"
- click "add new login..."
- click the button of whatever login provider you like (or enter one manually)